# Speech recognition using sphinx

Tags: java, speech-recognition, sphinx4

Currently I am working on Speech recognition using Sphinx. I added my own grammar file and appended to dictionary too.
But I am getting NullPointer Exception Error which is shown below

*Loading...
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.model.acoustic.WSJ_8gau_13dCep_16k_40mel_130Hz_6800Hz.ModelLoader.loadProperties(ModelLoader.java:372)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.model.acoustic.WSJ_8gau_13dCep_16k_40mel_130Hz_6800Hz.ModelLoader.getIsBinaryDefault(ModelLoader.java:386)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.model.acoustic.WSJ_8gau_13dCep_16k_40mel_130Hz_6800Hz.ModelLoader.newProperties(ModelLoader.java:346)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.util.props.ConfigurationManager.lookup(ConfigurationManager.java:214)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.util.props.ValidatingPropertySheet.getComponent(ValidatingPropertySheet.java:403)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.model.acoustic.WSJ_8gau_13dCep_16k_40mel_130Hz_6800Hz.Model.newProperties(Model.java:158)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.util.props.ConfigurationManager.lookup(ConfigurationManager.java:214)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.util.props.ValidatingPropertySheet.getComponent(ValidatingPropertySheet.java:403)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.flat.FlatLinguist.setupAcousticModel(FlatLinguist.java:204)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.flat.FlatLinguist.newProperties(FlatLinguist.java:167)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.util.props.ConfigurationManager.lookup(ConfigurationManager.java:214)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.util.props.ValidatingPropertySheet.getComponent(ValidatingPropertySheet.java:403)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.decoder.search.SimpleBreadthFirstSearchManager.newProperties(SimpleBreadthFirstSearchManager.java:183)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.util.props.ConfigurationManager.lookup(ConfigurationManager.java:214)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.util.props.ValidatingPropertySheet.getComponent(ValidatingPropertySheet.java:403)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.decoder.Decoder.newProperties(Decoder.java:71)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.util.props.ConfigurationManager.lookup(ConfigurationManager.java:214)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.util.props.ValidatingPropertySheet.getComponent(ValidatingPropertySheet.java:403)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.recognizer.Recognizer.newProperties(Recognizer.java:93)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.util.props.ConfigurationManager.lookup(ConfigurationManager.java:214)
    at demo.sphinx.helloworld.HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.java:49)*

How to Solve this problem....

Answer (score 0):

My Grammar File is

```
#JSGF V1.0;

/**
 * JSGF Grammar for Hello World example
 */

grammar hello;

public <greet> = (Good morning | Hello | Welcome ) ( Harinath | Raghunath | Vishnu );
```

My Config.xml file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!--
   Sphinx-4 Configuration file
-->

<!-- ******************************************************** -->
<!--  an4 configuration file                             -->
<!-- ******************************************************** -->

<config>        

    <!-- ******************************************************** -->
    <!-- frequently tuned properties                              -->
    <!-- ******************************************************** --> 

    <property name="logLevel" value="WARNING"/>

    <property name="absoluteBeamWidth"  value="-1"/>
    <property name="relativeBeamWidth"  value="1E-80"/>
    <property name="wordInsertionProbability" value="1E-36"/>
    <property name="languageWeight"     value="8"/>

    <property name="frontend" value="epFrontEnd"/>
    <property name="recognizer" value="recognizer"/>
    <property name="showCreations" value="false"/>


    <!-- ******************************************************** -->
    <!-- word recognizer configuration                            -->
    <!-- ******************************************************** --> 

    <component name="recognizer" type="edu.cmu.sphinx.recognizer.Recognizer">
        <property name="decoder" value="decoder"/>
        <propertylist name="monitors">
            <item>accuracyTracker </item>
            <item>speedTracker </item>
            <item>memoryTracker </item>
        </propertylist>
    </component>

    <!-- ******************************************************** -->
    <!-- The Decoder   configuration                              -->
    <!-- ******************************************************** --> 

    <component name="decoder" type="edu.cmu.sphinx.decoder.Decoder">
        <property name="searchManager" value="searchManager"/>
    </component>

    <component name="searchManager" 
        type="edu.cmu.sphinx.decoder.search.SimpleBreadthFirstSearchManager">
        <property name="logMath" value="logMath"/>
        <property name="linguist" value="flatLinguist"/>
        <property name="pruner" value="trivialPruner"/>
        <property name="scorer" value="threadedScorer"/>
        <property name="activeListFactory" value="activeList"/>
    </component>


    <component name="activeList" 
             type="edu.cmu.sphinx.decoder.search.PartitionActiveListFactory">
        <property name="logMath" value="logMath"/>
        <property name="absoluteBeamWidth" value="${absoluteBeamWidth}"/>
        <property name="relativeBeamWidth" value="${relativeBeamWidth}"/>
    </component>

    <component name="trivialPruner" 
                type="edu.cmu.sphinx.decoder.pruner.SimplePruner"/>

    <component name="threadedScorer" 
                type="edu.cmu.sphinx.decoder.scorer.ThreadedAcousticScorer">
        <property name="frontend" value="${frontend}"/>
        <property name="isCpuRelative" value="true"/>
        <property name="numThreads" value="0"/>
        <property name="minScoreablesPerThread" value="10"/>
        <property name="scoreablesKeepFeature" value="true"/>
    </component>

    <!-- ******************************************************** -->
    <!-- The linguist  configuration                              -->
    <!-- ******************************************************** -->

    <component name="flatLinguist" 
                type="edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.flat.FlatLinguist">
        <property name="logMath" value="logMath"/>
        <property name="grammar" value="jsgfGrammar"/>
        <property name="acousticModel" value="wsj"/>
        <property name="wordInsertionProbability" 
                value="${wordInsertionProbability}"/>
        <property name="languageWeight" value="${languageWeight}"/>
        <property name="unitManager" value="unitManager"/>
    </component>


    <!-- ******************************************************** -->
    <!-- The Grammar  configuration                               -->
    <!-- ******************************************************** -->

    <component name="jsgfGrammar" type="edu.cmu.sphinx.jsapi.JSGFGrammar">
        <property name="dictionary" value="dictionary"/>
        <property name="grammarLocation" 
             value="file : C:\Users\admin\eclipse-workspace\test\bin\demo\sphinx\helloworld"/>
        <property name="grammarName" value="hello"/>
    <property name="logMath" value="logMath"/>
    </component>


    <!-- ******************************************************** -->
    <!-- The Dictionary configuration                            -->
    <!-- ******************************************************** -->

    <component name="dictionary" 
        type="edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.dictionary.FastDictionary">
        <property name="dictionaryPath"
     value="resource:/WSJ_8gau_13dCep_16k_40mel_130Hz_6800Hz.Model!/edu/cmu/sphinx/model/acoustic/WSJ_8gau_13dCep_16k_40mel_130Hz_6800Hz/dict/cmudict.0.6d"/>
        <property name="fillerPath" 
     value="resource:/WSJ_8gau_13dCep_16k_40mel_130Hz_6800Hz.Model!/edu/cmu/sphinx/model/acoustic/WSJ_8gau_13dCep_16k_40mel_130Hz_6800Hz/dict/fillerdict"/>
        <property name="addSilEndingPronunciation" value="false"/>
        <property name="allowMissingWords" value="false"/>
        <property name="unitManager" value="unitManager"/>
    </component>

    <!-- ******************************************************** -->
    <!-- The acoustic model configuration                         -->
    <!-- ******************************************************** -->
    <component name="wsj" 
      type="edu.cmu.sphinx.model.acoustic.WSJ_8gau_13dCep_16k_40mel_130Hz_6800Hz.Model">
        <property name="loader" value="wsjLoader"/>
        <property name="unitManager" value="unitManager"/>
    </component>

    <component name="wsjLoader"
               type="edu.cmu.sphinx.model.acoustic.WSJ_8gau_13dCep_16k_40mel_130Hz_6800Hz.ModelLoader">
        <property name="logMath" value="logMath"/>
        <property name="unitManager" value="unitManager"/>
    </component>


    <!-- ******************************************************** -->
    <!-- The unit manager configuration                           -->
    <!-- ******************************************************** -->

    <component name="unitManager" 
        type="edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.acoustic.UnitManager"/>

    <!-- ******************************************************** -->
    <!-- The frontend configuration                               -->
    <!-- ******************************************************** -->

    <component name="frontEnd" type="edu.cmu.sphinx.frontend.FrontEnd">
        <propertylist name="pipeline">
            <item>microphone </item>
            <item>premphasizer </item>
            <item>windower </item>
            <item>fft </item>
            <item>melFilterBank </item>
            <item>dct </item>
            <item>liveCMN </item>
            <item>featureExtraction </item>
        </propertylist>
    </component>

    <!-- ******************************************************** -->
    <!-- The live frontend configuration                          -->
    <!-- ******************************************************** -->
    <component name="epFrontEnd" type="edu.cmu.sphinx.frontend.FrontEnd">
        <propertylist name="pipeline">
            <item>microphone </item>
            <item>speechClassifier </item>
            <item>speechMarker </item>
            <item>nonSpeechDataFilter </item>
            <item>premphasizer </item>
            <item>windower </item>
            <item>fft </item>
            <item>melFilterBank </item>
            <item>dct </item>
            <item>liveCMN </item>
            <item>featureExtraction </item>
        </propertylist>
    </component>

    <!-- ******************************************************** -->
    <!-- The frontend pipelines                                   -->
    <!-- ******************************************************** -->

    <component name="speechClassifier" 
               type="edu.cmu.sphinx.frontend.endpoint.SpeechClassifier">
        <property name="threshold" value="13"/>
    </component>

    <component name="nonSpeechDataFilter" 
               type="edu.cmu.sphinx.frontend.endpoint.NonSpeechDataFilter"/>

    <component name="speechMarker" 
               type="edu.cmu.sphinx.frontend.endpoint.SpeechMarker" >
        <property name="speechTrailer" value="50"/>
    </component>


    <component name="premphasizer" 
               type="edu.cmu.sphinx.frontend.filter.Preemphasizer"/>

    <component name="windower" 
               type="edu.cmu.sphinx.frontend.window.RaisedCosineWindower">
    </component>

    <component name="fft" 
            type="edu.cmu.sphinx.frontend.transform.DiscreteFourierTransform">
    </component>

    <component name="melFilterBank" 
        type="edu.cmu.sphinx.frontend.frequencywarp.MelFrequencyFilterBank">
    </component>

    <component name="dct" 
            type="edu.cmu.sphinx.frontend.transform.DiscreteCosineTransform"/>

    <component name="liveCMN" 
               type="edu.cmu.sphinx.frontend.feature.LiveCMN"/>

    <component name="featureExtraction" 
               type="edu.cmu.sphinx.frontend.feature.DeltasFeatureExtractor"/>

    <component name="microphone" 
               type="edu.cmu.sphinx.frontend.util.Microphone">
        <property name="closeBetweenUtterances" value="false"/>
    </component>


    <!-- ******************************************************* -->
    <!--  monitors                                               -->
    <!-- ******************************************************* -->

    <component name="accuracyTracker" 
                type="edu.cmu.sphinx.instrumentation.AccuracyTracker">
        <property name="recognizer" value="${recognizer}"/>
        <property name="showAlignedResults" value="false"/>
        <property name="showRawResults" value="false"/>
    </component>

    <component name="memoryTracker" 
                type="edu.cmu.sphinx.instrumentation.MemoryTracker">
        <property name="recognizer" value="${recognizer}"/>
    <property name="showSummary" value="false"/>
    <property name="showDetails" value="false"/>
    </component>

    <component name="speedTracker" 
                type="edu.cmu.sphinx.instrumentation.SpeedTracker">
        <property name="recognizer" value="${recognizer}"/>
        <property name="frontend" value="${frontend}"/>
    <property name="showSummary" value="true"/>
    <property name="showDetails" value="false"/>
    </component>


    <!-- ******************************************************* -->
    <!--  Miscellaneous components                               -->
    <!-- ******************************************************* -->

    <component name="logMath" type="edu.cmu.sphinx.util.LogMath">
        <property name="logBase" value="1.0001"/>
        <property name="useAddTable" value="true"/>
    </component>

</config>
```